# How to make my animation play once?

Tags: animation, unreal, skeletal-animation

In 3ds max, I've made a Cannon that sets itself up, but I only want this animation to play once, here's where I'm trying to make it loop only once:

[image]

When I click the toggle at the bottom, it stops the animation for constantly looping, but when I click 'Save', and run my game, it still continues to loop.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the animation to stop on the last frame. To do this, open up your Animation Blueprint, and select the animation state associated with your animation in the Viewport. Then simply uncheck the 'Loop Animation' box under the Settings options of the details panel, as shown in the picture below. I hope that answers your question!

[image]